# How to simulate a key press when another key is pressed?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am trying to get the delete key to do what the spacebar normally does. In other words, when the user clicks the delete in a UITextField, I want a space to appear instead.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let  char = string.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    let isBackSpace = strcmp(char, "\\b")
    if (isBackSpace == -92) {
        print("Delete was pressed")
        return false
    }

    return true
 }
```

I know that this only disables the delete key, but how would I move forward? Also, the space would replace the selected text (there is always some text that is selected).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `textField` parameter is the text field in which the user is working. You are free to do there whatever you like. So, in addition to returning `false`, and just before doing so, change the `text` of the `textField` to whatever you want.

If what you want to do is append a space to the text, an easy way is to fetch `textField.text!`, append a space to that string, and set `textField.text`. Or if you want to replace the current selection with a space, instead of letting it be removed, do that to `textField.text`, using the `range` parameter to tell you where the space should go.

In other words, if you know anything at all about how to work with strings, you can do that to the string that is `textField.text` as part of this method.

There are other ways using the UITextInput protocol, which allows you to pretend to be the keyboard. For example, just saying `textField.insertText(" ")` might give you desired result, but you'll have to try it and see.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it clearer, but the space wouldn't be added to the end. The space would replace the selected text (there is always some text that is selected)

Comment: Fine, and the `range` parameter tells you what that selected text is. So replace that range of the text with your space. I still don't see what the hard part is!